# Code blocks deciding to go out of the frame

Tags: bug, code-formatting

I just recently came across a bug, I saw [a post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68993007/how-to-use-python-selenium-with-wsl2#68993007) with code like this `foo bar`, with (`), but somehow it became like this:

[image]

It went under the "Featured on Meta" and "The Overflow Bug" banners and went out of the page...

This is surely a bug...

Comment: Reproed on Chrome but not Firefox. Looking at the source for the question though there are 100 redundant spaces in that inline code block, perhaps OP thought that was a good way to bring text to the next line.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Well even like that the code shouldn't let that happen...

Comment: Some code doesn't want to be framed ...

Comment: not the first time it's reported: see [last year on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/347630/786798). Transforming it to a code block "solves" this because the markup generated is `<pre><code></code></pre>`

Comment: That is not to say that this is not a problem: it is easily solved by giving the `<code>` a `display: inline-block` rule (example [of the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9qbU.png))

Comment: @U12-Forward yeah, maybe this time it will get a [status-review] tag and finally fixed :(

Answer (score 4):

Give it 6 to 8 weeks as usual.

In the meantime, you can use the following techniques to work around that:

1. Switch inline code of this size to a code block by using fences (triple backticks) or four-space indentation as chances are there's simply a lot of significant whitespaces, or it should've been a multiline block in the first place:

   ```
   this                                    line                      is                   quite               long               (you           should              see               a              horizontal                        scroll                                           bar)
   ```

   Fixed image for posterity:

   [image: code block version]
2. Use <s>the force</s> a custom CSS ruleset to override the `display` rule for `<code>` elements to `inline-block` (see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display)) which makes them take the best of both worlds (inline view for short blocks, multiline view for long blocks):

   ```css
   code {
       display: inline-block;
   }
   ```

   Here is how this would look like for long blocks (short ones will stay the same):

   [image: inline code if using display: inline-block]
3. As an alternative CSS technique, you can override the `white-space` rule to `break-spaces` for `<code>` elements instead (see [MDN ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space)). This gives a similar result but preserves the inline appearance even if the code ends up spanning multiple lines:

   ```css
   code {
       white-space: break-spaces;
   }
   ```

   And here is how it would look like:

   [image: inline code if using white-space: break-spaces]

Comment: Ah that's a clever hack! Thanks for your input! and the 6 to 8 weeks meme lol :)

Comment: NP - SE is a never-ending source of UI bugs to fiddle with :)

Comment: Haha! It's an amazingly huge network! having bugs is definite! :)

Comment: @U12-Forward I think it's called "We forgot to create test.." ;)